# Change border style in Gallery

Tags: android, border, gallery

I am taking [this](http://www.androidpeople.com/android-gallery-imageview-example/) tutorial. As you can see on [this](http://www.androidpeople.com/wp-content/uploads/2010/05/imagegallery1.png) image, the standard grey border is applied to all elements in the gallery. I would like to remove this rather ugly border, or, actually, make it a 1 px border instead (or just so the images can be distinguished from each other).
I tried removing this line:

```
imgView.setBackgroundResource(GalItemBg);
```

That removes the border, but then the images overlap each other and it's still not very pretty.

So, how do I change the border? And how do I get the gallery elements to not overlap each other?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I'm sure you've already discovered an answer for this problem, but as there's none posted, here's one now!

You can place each of your `imgView` objects inside of a `RelativeLayout` with a black background and a 1 padding.  Then return the `RelativeLayout` object containing the `ImageView` instead of returning the ImageView itself.

```
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)
{
    ImageView imgView = new ImageView(m_Context);
    // do stuff initializing your imgView as before
    RelativeLayout borderImg = new RelativeLayout(m_Context);
    borderImg.setPadding(1,1,1,1);
    borderImg.setBackgroundColor(0xff000000);
    borderImg.addView(imgView);
    return borderImg;
}
```

Finally, it is much easier to enforce a spacing between your `Gallery` images by using the Gallery method `setSpacing(int pixels)` to put a space between each `Gallery` object.  You won't get the black border around them, but the `Gallery` background will be visible between and behind them.

Comment: That gives me a ClassCastException inspite of casting it to a View.

Comment: Check your code, I just retested this code exactly and had no problems.  This code goes in your Gallery adapter.

Comment: Thanks for re-checking. I still have the same problem. Mine extends BaseAdapter ...maybe you are working with ArrayAdapter<T>?

Comment: Hey Sagar, do you mind posting the code you're having a problem with?  Where is the ClassCastException occuring?  At the return statement?  I too am extending BaseAdapter and I've had no problems with the above code where imgView is an ImageView or a TextView.

Comment: sure, the code is exactly the same as here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6058609/android-gallerys-getview-returning-incorrect-position In the getView() method, just when the ImageView object is instantiated, I added your 4 lines above and returned the RelativeLayout view by casting it to (View). I get a ClassCastException at getView() methods line where I return the RelativeLayout

Comment: Hey Sagar, check your above referenced thread for my fix for that question, as well as the `getView` method that you'll need to get a 20 pixel border around your images.

Comment: Thanks Thomson for all your efforts! I will try the solution.

Comment: Thanks Thomson Comer, that works great! I used your posted code + the setSpacing command.